# How to let the manager know that I am available for the position I rejected earlier

Tags: software-development

I am a consultant at this company for long time now. I have a very good reputation as a person with good technical know-how, highly experienced in most of the bread and butter products of the company and being a fearless speaker.

In the past my manager had asked me if I am interested in the Sr developer role position but I let the opportunity go saying I am only looking for the lead position since I have so much of experience at the company. This happened about 3 years back. But I noticed that there are a no lead positions open during this time and looks like there will be none in near future. And now I think I have spent enough time in this company and not motivated anymore to go outside looking for the full time job and I am even satisfied with the sr developer role if not the lead. But now my manager is not even asking me if I am interested to join as a full timer.

My question is - Since I have rejected the same position earlier, how can I let the manager know that I am ok joining as a sr developer role. I don't want to sound like a loser or that I am not competent enough to find better opportunities elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll tell you my perspective as a technology lead/delivery manager, I managed, trained, and coached multiple teams: If a person tells me that they are looking for something specific – I won't offer them anything else in future, especially if they are aiming at something that could be considered higher than offered, because there is a risk offending them. As in – they think they deserve a lead position, and I'm offering a mere senior engineering role.

If your manager is anything like me – they might never ask you again, until they have a lead role that they think you could do.

So – my advice would be to be straight with them, and ask them if they have a senior engineering role. Now, because it happened 3 years ago – it's pretty safe to assume that that role is long gone, but it doesn't matter. If you acted politely a cordially it's perfectly ok to approach them, if they don't have a role, feel free to ask them to recommend you.

Answer (score 5):

3 years is a long time in software development to change your mind about where you want your career to go.  The easiest path here is to approach your manager, who has just been assuming you aren't interested for years now.  Be sure you only convey the positive, that you are excited to pursue this opportunity in the company, because of (name something like a company change in direction, technologies change, new people on the team, etc.)  This doesn't have to come off as a negative and won't be considered a negative unless you make it that.

Answer (score 1):

Talk to your manager.

“Remember 3 years ago when you asked me if I’m interested in such and such position...well it kinda sounds interesting to me now and wanted to check with you if that position is still open.”

Worst case scenario is the position is not open, but in case it opens up again, your boss is already aware that you taking the spot is a possibility.